# Number format of a query in access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created a query in access using VBA, and I want to change the number format of the last two columns to * #.##0,00;* (#.##0,00);* -00

I didn't find how to do it. Here's what I did:

```vb
Sub orcMensal(periodo As String)

Dim rs As QueryDef
Dim SQL1 As String
Dim ano As String
Dim tabelaCA As String
Dim tabelaRealizado As String


tabelaCA = "[ORCAMENTO_CA_20" & Right(periodo, 2) & "]"
tabelaRealizado = "[" & periodo & "_MA]"


SQL1 = "SELECT " & tabelaCA & ".coger AS [Codigo Coger], " _
        & tabelaCA & ".[Descricao], " _
        & tabelaCA & ".[" & periodo & "] AS [Orcamento], " _
        & tabelaRealizado & ".[REALIZADO] AS [Realizado], " _
        & "(" & tabelaRealizado & ".[REALIZADO] - " & tabelaCA & ".[" & periodo & "]) AS [Diferenca] " _
        & "FROM " & tabelaCA _
        & " INNER JOIN " & tabelaRealizado & " ON" _
        & " (" & tabelaCA & ".[coger] = " & tabelaRealizado & ".[COD_ES] AND " _
        & tabelaCA & ".[Titular] = " & tabelaRealizado & ".[TITULAR]);"



Debug.Print SQL1
Set rs = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(periodo, SQL1)
DoCmd.OpenQuery rs.Name, , acReadOnly



End Sub
```

Comment: Can I use the Format function in the SQL string? The format actually is "#.##0,00; (#.##0,00); -00", but I don't know why in the access format box of the column I'm using as a model it uses asterisks.

Comment: 1) 1000000,5023  **>>>>**  1.000.000,50;              
2) -5200000,7833  **>>>>**  (5.200.000,78);               
3) 0  **>>>>**  -;

Comment: I've tried using Format in the SQL string and it worked! Thanks. But how do I put in this specific format showed above?

Comment: Try something like this  Format([periodo],"#,##0.00") AS xxx (or in your case you may need to switch the commas and decimals like '#.##0,00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Format function in the SQL query, like @Wayne G. Dunn commented. The format that I wanted was

```
1) 1000000,5023 >>>> 1.000.000,50;  
2) -5200000,7833 >>>> (5.200.000,78);  
3) 0 >>>> -
```

So I used **'#,##0.00; (#,##0.00); -'** in the format function, here's how the query looks:

```vb
SQL1 = "SELECT " & tabelaCA & ".coger AS [Codigo Coger], " _
        & tabelaCA & ".[Descricao], " _
        & "Format(" & tabelaCA & ".[" & periodo & "], '#,##0.00; (#,##0.00); -') AS [Orcamento], FORMAT(" _
        & tabelaRealizado & ".[REALIZADO], '#,##0.00; (#,##0.00); -') AS [Realizado], " _
        & "Format((" & tabelaRealizado & ".[REALIZADO] - " & tabelaCA & ".[" & periodo & "]), '#,##0.00; (#,##0.00); -') AS [Diferenca] " _
        & "FROM " & tabelaCA _
        & " LEFT JOIN " & tabelaRealizado & " ON" _
        & " (" & tabelaCA & ".[coger] = " & tabelaRealizado & ".[COD_ES] AND " _
        & tabelaCA & ".[Titular] = " & tabelaRealizado & ".[TITULAR])" _
        & "WHERE " & tabelaCA & ".coger <> '';"
```